# Invalid postback or callback argument. When dropdown list populated with jquery and there is a postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have two dropdown list boxes on change of first I want to fill the second one.
I have written a jquery for this as follow

```
function BindModel() {
var makeCode = $('#ddMake').val();
var ddModel = $("#ddModel");
if (makeCode == "0") {
    return false;
}
else {
    $("#loading").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Services/GetModels.ashx",
        data: { 'makeCode': makeCode },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#loading").hide();
            $.each(data, function () {
                ddModel.append($("<option />").val(this.ModelCode).text(this.ModelName));
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#loading").hide();
        }
    });
}
}
```

I have a generic http handler as follows

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        if( context.Request["makeCode"]!=null)
        {
            var makeCode = context.Request["makeCode"].Trim();
            var lobjSearchProps = new CSearchAllProps
            {
                SearchValue = "%",
                MakeCode = makeCode
            };
            var allModelProps = new 
            CModelRestrictionLogic().GetModels(lobjSearchProps).ToList();
            context.Response.Write(JSONHelper.GetJSON(allModelProps));    
        }
```

where `CModelRestrictionLogic().GetModels(lobjSearchProps)` is my function which fetches data from the database.
and `CModelRestrictionLogic().GetModels(lobjSearchProps)` converts the list to JSON.
Every thing is working fine. But whenever I post back it is giving an error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
> using  in configuration or <%@
> Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
> purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
> events originate from the server control that originally rendered
> them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
> ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
> register the postback or callback data for validation.

I know the reason because I have filled the dropdown list from jquery so it is getting an error.
I have also written function on init to fill the data from posted back values as follow

```
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        var postedOptionValue = Request.Form[ddModel.UniqueID];
        ddModel.Items.Add(new ListItem(postedOptionValue));
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

How can I get rid of this value? I don't want to use enableEventValidation="false" because it is a security concern.

Comment: I am looking for an answer to this, too.  I am wondering if the only option is to change the server control to a `SELECT` element and write the selected value to a hidden field.  That's a huge change, so I am hoping I don't have experiment with that.