# Bind DropDownList with client side JS PageMethods

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, pagemethods

I am trying to `bind a state ddl by onChange of country ddl` using `PageMethods`

**JS Codes in aspx**

```
function GetStates() {
 var e = document.getElementById("<%=ddlCountry.ClientID %>");
 var Countryid = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 PageMethods.GetStates(Countryid,ShowStates);
}

function ShowStates(results)
{
  document.getElementById("li2").innerHTML=results;
}
```

**.CS Codes**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetStates(int Cid)
{
    DataSet dstFillState = Tbl_State.FillDDLState(Cid);
    string strHTML = "<select id='ddlState' name='ddlState'>";
    foreach (DataRow row in dstFillState.Tables[0].Rows) // Loop over the rows.
    {
     strHTML = strHTML + "<option value=" + (string)row["Id"] +">" + (string)row["State"] +"</option>";
    }
    strHTML = strHTML + "</select>";
    return strHTML;
}
```

**ERROR Msg**

```
The server method 'GetStates' failed with the following error: System.InvalidCastException-- Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
```

I get this error as a browser PopUp.What am I missing here ?

**SOLUTION**

Here problem i think was same name GetStates for both CS and JS functions,I altered and it worked.

Comment: don't do (string)row["Id"]. rather do Convert.ToString(row["Id"]) (and all other fields) or row["Id"].ToString() with proper null check

Comment: @ManishMishra No still same error,I tried x.toString() and convert.toString(x)

Comment: are u sending an int data to your GetStates method?? i mean is ur CountryId an int? if it is not try changing it to int or try changing argument type of ur GetStates method to string Cid, and convert it to int inside the method

Comment: @ManishMishra its called form JS ie 'var Countryid = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;' ,so should i convert it to int and then pass ?

Comment: yeah you can do that, do this. var Countryid= parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value)

Comment: I did PageMethods.GetStates(parseInt(Countryid),ShowStates); No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the line

```
foreach (DataRow row in dstFillState.Tables[0].Rows) // Loop over the rows.
{
 strHTML = strHTML + "<option value=" + (string)row["Id"] +">" + (string)row["State"] +"</option>";
}
```

you should use like this

```
foreach (DataRow row in dstFillState.Tables[0].Rows) // Loop over the rows.
{
 strHTML = strHTML + "<option value='" +row["Id"].ToString() +"'>" + row["State"].ToString() +"</option>";
}
```

or even

```
foreach (DataRow row in dstFillState.Tables[0].Rows) // Loop over the rows.
{
 strHTML = strHTML + "<option value='" + row["Id"] +"'>" + row["State"] +"</option>";
}
```

here is a good example

 [Invalid postback or callback argument. When dropdown list populated with jquery and there is a postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490236/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-when-dropdown-list-populated-with-jquery)

Comment: No still same error,I tried x.toString() and convert.toString(x)

Comment: There is some other problem. Not in this line.

Comment: check this function 'Tbl_State.FillDDLState(Cid)' does it take a string or int

Comment: That Id comes from JS 'var Countryid = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;'.I have doubts here,bcos I cant breakpoint to chk since its coming from JS.

Comment: you can put break point and see. It doesn't matter from where the result is coming. Just put a alert before the function call with the selected value and see the value which is being passed from the java-script. And put a break-point on the server side code and see what value you are getting

Comment: JS values are passed correctly as "1","2" etc but in CS breakpoints are never hit,also did int conversion at JS 'parseInt(Countryid)'

Comment: If it is not hitting the cs break-point it means you are not able to call the .cs method from java-script. First try to call a small method of .cs from java-script.

Comment: Alrite,I did a small pageMethod and the problem i think was same name GetStates for both CS and JS functions,It worked !Thanks a lot for your time and effort.