# How to get drop box selected value where drop box data were being populated in client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a page that has 2 drop boxes. The data in the 2nd drop box will change depending on the selected data in the 1st drop box.Data on changed for the 1st drop box is in the client script.Now I tried to get the selected value on the 2nd drop box in the server side but got none.How to fix this issue?

Here are codes:

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="hidden" id="ddlFormatOriginalData" name="ddlFormatOriginalData" runat="server" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="d1" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <input type="hidden" id="ddlFormatOriginalData" name="ddlFormatOriginalData" runat="server" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="d2" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Javascript side

```
$addHandler(ddlFormat, 'change', upDateD2);

function upDateD2(sender) {

    var PaperList = $get(ddlPaperStockID); // gets the list for a certain selected value in d1

    for (j = 0; j < PaperList.options.length; j++) {
        // added List here to d2
    }
}
```

Server side

```
string val = d2.selected.value;
```

But I got nothing for val though in firebug the different list for the d2 drop box were shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like follows

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
     var postedOptionValue = Request.Form[d2.UniqueID];
     d2.Items.Add(new ListItem(postedOptionValue));
     base.OnInit(e);
}
```

But you should take care of the following exception

```
Invalid postback or callback argument.
```

Event validation is enabled using

```
   <pages enableEventValidation="true"/>
```

in configuration or

```
    <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>
```

in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.
If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.
RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

### Edit 1

More reading -
[Invalid postback or callback argument. When dropdown list populated with jquery and there is a postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490236/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-when-dropdown-list-populated-with-jquery)

Comment: @RJUy why are you using hidden field.

Comment: Hello Krshekhar, thanks for this info.  I'll try to implement it now and I'll let you know if everything is okey.. The hidden field has some other purpose... :)

Comment: when I added this one EnableEventValidation="true" got an error when I submit the button

Comment: based on my research on having enableEventValidation="true" will cause a security issue.  I think this solution will not be accepted by the company.  I have tried another solution by setting the value on the server side instead.  I hope this one will work.  Though thanks a lot for the help.  I really appreciated your time.

Comment: You can take benefit of html `list option` and set the selected value in a hidden field. This approach won't require the `EnableEventValidation="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using JQuery data - for example:

```
<div id="test" data-cool="demo"></div>
```

and in JS:

```
$("#test").data("cool"); // outputs: 'demo'
```

you could also use it to set update variables:

```
$("#test").data("cool", "really cool!"); // updates the data-cool field to: 'really cool!'
```