# Bind dropdownlist based on the selected value of another dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I wanted to know what is the best way to create 2 dropdown lists in a way that the 2nd dropdown list depends on the choise of the 1st one.

I have 2 tables at SQL DB which holds values for the 2 dropdwon lists , which I drawing at page load function into a 2 list of strings, each list to a dropdwon list.
How can I implement that the 2nd dropdown list will depend on the choise that was made at 1st dropdwon list and that won't post back to the server? it should all be perform at client side... 
lets say for example that in the 1 dropdown list those are values to be shown and chosen: "Software", "Machinery" and "Administration" and lets say if I chose "Software" the 2nd dropdown list will show me those values "Web Development", "Hardware QA", "Software Devlopment","Hardware Devlopment", "Software  QA", but if chose "Machinery" at the 1st dropdown list those values won't be shown instead of them it will show "Mechanical Engineering", "Product Manager", "Draftsman".

for the record I'll already made a method which "grabs" the info from the SQL DB to 2 lists all I need is this mechanism that is running only on the client side (maybe javascript?) without a postback to server...

thanks for your help everyone

Comment: What have to tried yet? Did you google for this? What results you got? Which websites or already posted questions you visited?

Comment: The best way would be to use ajax. link : http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Comment: simple is call selected_change event of first dropdown after bind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ajax control toolkit then here is the link
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Else you want to fill it from jquery or javascript here is the link
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/97/Cascading-DropDownLists-with-jQuery-and-ASP.NET

But if you go with the second link then you will have some security issue.
[Invalid postback or callback argument. When dropdown list populated with jquery and there is a postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490236/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-when-dropdown-list-populated-with-jquery)